# apache2 gives 404 before rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a rewrite rule in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^vt$ vt.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

if file 'vt' exists in my website directory, the rewrite is done well.
but if file 'vt' doesn't exist, apache2 just gives a 404 error.

so it seems apache2 do rewrite after it checks file stat.
How do I fix this?

---

I think this is a bug. I use this rule finnally to avoid use two files (vt and vt.php).

```
RewriteRule ^vt$ - [H=application/x-httpd-php]
```

Comment: Sorry, but what do you expect to happen? I'm confused about what you think is broken.

Comment: Is this your complete .htaccess OR you have some other rules also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like there may be 2 things happening here.

1. Mod_rewrite doesn't appear to be loaded
2. `Multiviews` is making it *appear* as if mod_rewrite is loaded

What `Multiviews` does, is part of mod_negotiation which tries to "guess" what the request is for if it is missing things like an extension. So with `Multiviews` turned on, if it sees a request for `/vt` and the file `vt` doesn't exist, it guesses and finds `/vt.php` and serves that, otherwise it doesn't nothing and returns a 404. This would make it appear as if the mod_rewrite rule is actually being applied. If mod_rewrite is actually turned on, then it would apply the rule even if mod_negotiation was turned on and the file was missing (which would result in a 404).

So 1. make sure that mod_rewrite is actually loaded. To do this, check your httpd.conf file and there should be a line that looks like this (uncommented):

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Or you can try removing the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` container, if you get a 500 server error, mod_rewrite *isn't* loaded.

Then 2. add this line in your htaccess file to turn off `Multiviews`:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Comment: thanks. I think this might be a bug. I'm sure module rewrite is loaded. Finally I changed my rewrite rule to :  RewriteRule ^vt$ - [H=application/x-httpd-php]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define "/" as the "**404 error document**" by appending the following line to your *.htaccess* file, so the visitors return to your *homepage* or *index.php*.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

If you want them to be redirected to a **specific** page, simply use

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/your/404/file.ext
```

Comment: Read the question again. OP's problem is getting 404 when file `vt` is there.